# got error when try to change the time to monthly instead of daily snapshot

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas series with different fileds(objects) one of them is the date and the original type of that is `<class 'str'>` and with this format `"2022-07-09"`. for having count of daily snapshots I used the following code

```
 if num_domains <= max_domains_for_plotting:
       df_domains_snapshot = df.groupby([dat_col, col]).size().reset_index(name='count')
       df_domains_snapshot['pct'] = df_domains_snapshot['count'] / df_domains_snapshot.groupby([dat_col])['count'].transform('sum')
       df_domains_all = df.groupby([col]).size().reset_index(name='count')
       df_domains_all['pct'] = df_domains_all['count'] / df_domains_all['count'].sum()
       stackedbar_abs = df.groupby([dat_col, col]).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
       stackedbar_pct = df.groupby(dat_col)[col].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(col).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

and it works. now I need count of monthly snapshot then I added the following line before the above code to have just month and year

```
df['dat_col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df[dat_col],errors='coerce').dt.to_period('M')
dat_col1 = df['dat_col1']
```

the result for the `df['dat_col1']` field was like `"2022-07"` but when I replaced dat_col in `df.groupby([dat_col, col])` in the above code with `dat_col1` I got the following error:

```
uncaught exception: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible sample of your data set?

Comment: the original dateTime samples are like the following:     ' 2022-05-03'

  '2022-05-03'

 '2022-05-03'
and after using pd.to_datetime(df[dat_col],errors='coerce').dt.to_period('M') the results for  df['dat_col1']  are like these: '2022-05'

    '2022-05'

' 2022-05'

'2022-06' I expected that if I put dat_cal1 in group by I could have a monthly count but actually the dat_col1 is a data frame with two columns index and above date. and I think  that's why I got this error